# Sublime Text v3 editor closing itself automatically after running build, for C#

Tags: c#, build, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 (beta) portable version on Window 64 bit machine.
I am trying following build :

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v3.5\\csc.exe", "$file_name", "D:\\foo\\Hello1.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^[]*File \"(...*?)\", line([0-9]*)", 
    "selector": "source.csharp",
}
```

When I build, Sublime just closes whole editor (even if other files are open in it). If I run same build code using command prompt it runs as expected (and exe file gets executed). There are no compilation and run error in it (its sample Hello World code).

I have found package called, SublimeMSBuild, but currently its too much for me, as I am learning language, and can't find detailed example of SublimeMSBuild package use.

What I tried:

```
# gives error
"cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v3.5\\csc.exe", "$file_name", &&, "D:\\foo\\Hello1.exe"]

# runs properly, but then I have to run exe file manually
"cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v3.5\\csc.exe", "$file_name"]
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

I also have similar issue. Sublime editor closes itself after some time whether any file opened or not. But If I open a file and save with or without any change in that file then editor works seamlessly fine.

My build version is 3103 and OS is MS Windows 7

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. But I think I won't be using Sublime anymore, as I have been learning and using Vim (GVim) past 6 months. Both these editors pose one more problem for me i.e not supporting Devanagri and other Unicode fonts. But Vim feels far better than Sublime, and for Unicode related issue, I am using Notepad++ on windows and Gedit on Linux.